# saving number field with a value of zero in Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel

I have a form that accepts delivery of products which I noticed if I enter 0 in the quantity field it doesn't save in the database even if I add data in the calendar or in Notes field.

[image]

I already commented out the `\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,`iin kernel.php still doesn't work.

how can I forced laravel to save my data even if I want to put 0 in quantity? thanks in advance!

**update**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();

    $items = [];

    for ($i = 0; $i <= count($input['order_id']); $i++) {

        if (empty($input['stock_in_qty'][$i]) || !is_numeric($input['stock_in_qty'][$i])) continue;

        $acceptItem = [
            'order_id'      => $input['order_id'][$i],
            'product_id'    => $input['product_id'][$i],
            'order_item_id' => $input['order_item_id'][$i],
            'delivery_date' => $input['delivery_date'][$i],
            'company_id'    => $input['company_id'][$i],
            // 'stock_in_qty' => intval($input['stock_in_qty'])[$i],
            'stock_in_qty'  => $input['stock_in_qty'][$i],
            // 'stock_out_qty' => $input['stock_out_qty'][$i],
            // 'transfer_to' => $input['transfer_to'][$i],
            'delivery_note' => $input['delivery_note'][$i],
            'user_id'       => $input['user_id'][$i],
        ];
        array_push($items, Warehouse1stocks::create($acceptItem));

        $stockSummary = Warehouse1StockSummaries::firstOrCreate(
            ['product_id' => $input['product_id'][$i]],
            ['qty_in'  => $input['stock_in_qty'][$i],
             'qty_out' => null,
            ]);

        if (!$stockSummary->wasRecentlyCreated) {
            $stockSummary->increment('qty_in', $input['stock_in_qty'][$i]);
        }
    }

    if ($input['rd'] == $input['stock_in_qty'] || $input['rd'] == 0) {
        $order_idAcceptedItem = $acceptItem['order_id'];
        $setStatus = \App\Orders::where('id', '=', $order_idAcceptedItem)->first();
        if ($setStatus) {
            $setStatus->status_id = 4;
        }
        $setStatus->save();
    } else {
        $order_idAcceptedItem = $acceptItem['order_id'];
        $setStatus = \App\Orders::where('id', '=', $order_idAcceptedItem)->first();
        if ($setStatus) {
            $setStatus->status_id = 3;
        }
        $setStatus->save();
    }

    return redirect()->route('orders.index');
}
```

Comment: what is the column type of quantity field?

Comment: Hi @PrafullaKumarSahu its  $table->integer('stock_in_qty')->unsigned();

Comment: How's your controller's update method? You can add a null check there like `$model->quantity = $request->quantity ?? 0;`

Comment: 0 is probably being converted to `false`, you should be explicit about types in cases like this, i.e: `(int) $request->quantity` (after validating that it's a number).

Comment: hi @TahaPaksu actually I have no update method I only have the store method.

Comment: @Lito try what sam is telling as unsigned should allow 0.

Comment: If you don't know how to do that then please share your code for the `store` method and we can guide you.

Comment: yes @PrafullaKumarSahu I just thinking how should I do that?

Comment: share your code of store method.

Comment: ok @sam I'll just update my question

Comment: I just update my question

Comment: @Lito Can you var_dump `$input['stock_in_qty']` ?

Comment: or just make it (int)$input['stock_in_qty'] and try.

Comment: dd($input['stock_in_qty']);   -- >    array:3 [▼
  0 => "0"
  1 => "213"
  2 => "21"
]

Comment: see your `0` is string, not an int

Comment: I also think there is some syntax mistake on `['qty_in'     => $input['stock_in_qty'][$i],` where the first square bracket ends? any way make it `(int)$input['stock_in_qty']` try to save and let me know what happens.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190167/discussion-between-prafulla-kumar-sahu-and-lito).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`empty()` will return `true` with `0` or `'0'` which will mean that if you try to change the quantity to 0 the `for` loop will just continue on to the next loop. If you need to check if the value exists you can instead use `isset()`.

Changing your first if statement to the following should be all you need:

```
 if(!isset($input['stock_in_qty'][$i]) || !is_numeric($input['stock_in_qty'][$i])) continue;
```

Comment: exactly @RossWilson that is what happening.

Comment: I just applied your suggestion @RossWilson. I am receiving Undefined offset: 3

Comment: the zero is now saving in my database but I am having  ErrorException (E_NOTICE)
Undefined offset: 3? and it is pointing to  if(!is_numeric($input['stock_in_qty'][$i])) continue;

Comment: @Lito I've updated my answer. If you need to check if the value exists then use `isset` instead of `empty`. I would also suggest looking at using https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#available-validation-rules instead of inline validation.

Comment: thanks you @RossWilson! I'll take note of that. I believe you already save me twice! :)